# Making a react-native TextInput readonly

Tags: react-native

I want to make a text input readonly in my RN application. I tried to set an editable prop but it did not work properly. How can I achieve this?

```js
<DetailInput
  inputStyle={styles.inputStyles} 
  height={120}
  width={width - 40}
  multiline={true}
  numberOfLines={6}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  maxLength={500}
  editable={!userRegistrationInProgress}
  onChangeText={value => this.statementChangedHandler(value)}
/>

const detailInput = props => {

    return (
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        style=
          {[
            props.inputStyle,
            { height: props.height, width: props.width},
            !props.valid && props.touched ? props.invalidInput : null
          ]}
      />
    );
}

export default detailInput;
```

Comment: editable={false} works fine for TextInput can you provide more information what may be the problem. also console your !userRegistrationInProgress to see its value and assure it is Boolean.

Answer (score 47):

```
 <TextInput
    value = "Read Only"
    editable = {false}
 />
```

Set editable false to make the TextInput read only.

To change the text color back to black when the TextInput has a non-null value, set the style property `color` to `"black"`. (It defaults to a grey color when the value is null or the value is non-null but the TextInput is not editable.

```
 <TextInput
    style = {{ color: "black" }}
    value = "Read Only"
    editable = {false}
 />
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but then I have a new problem, the text changes color, it becomes gray. How can I set the Input field to "read-only" without changing the color?

Comment: just set the color to black: `<TextInput editable={false} style={{ color: 'black' }}/>`

Comment: How to make multiline `TextInput` scrollable when `editable = {false}`?

Answer (score 20):

A better `readonly` Text input:

```js
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <TextInput value="I am read only" editable={false} />
</View>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#pointerevents

Comment: How to make multiline `TextInput` scrollable when `editable = {false}`?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more prop besides `editable` which allows to do that starting from `0.71` version:

```js
 <TextInput readOnly={true} value="Read Only" />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#readonly

Note that Typescript currently gives an error when using this prop (though it works fine), this bug will be fixed in future releases
(see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/39281).